# How to force to Linux to connect only 5GHz channel?

Tags: networking, wireless

In my environment two wifi channels are available but my Linux client is connect to 2.5 GHz channel only. Is there any solution to force the linux client to connect to 5 GHz channel only. If i disable the 2.5 GHz from Access point it works but i need any solution from Linux side? All the Access points have same SSID and we are not allowed to change it.

Comment: Maybe your network device supports only 2.4GHz

Comment: if i disable the 2.4GHz it connects to 5GHz but some other devices available on same frequency so not possible to disable it.

Comment: _Maybe_ this helps: [How to disable “N” Wireless Mode RTL8192on a Thinkpad Edge 15 Core i5:](https://askubuntu.com/q/41259) but the question is old; not sure whether it still applies.

Comment: @PerlDuck i check the link but the command "sudo iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g" not work on my system. Error "command not found"

Answer (score 13):

For any distro with Network Manager, this is an editable parameter in the `nm-connection-editor` UI. You may wish to change this setting for each saved connection since not all routers are created equal. This feature has existed in Network Manager since [2008](https://github.com/GNOME/network-manager-applet/commit/135eebb3a4f9499a4c4d39dff2fee666f88fbb7d#diff-3c89311b58772c4f352d5d5bce5d1b05) (which appears to correspond to [NM Applet >= 0.7.2](https://github.com/GNOME/network-manager-applet/releases/tag/NETWORKMANAGER_APPLET_0_7_2)).

1. Run `nm-connection-editor` or open your network settings and edit your WiFi connection. If you're on a distro like Arch, you might want to install [this package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Additional_interfaces).
2. There is a `Band` option under the `Wi-Fi` tab that will let you select `Automatic`, `A (5 GHz)`, or `B/G (2.4 GHz)`. If you don't have the 5 GHz option, you might need to debug further (I can't say definitively from lack of experience with older systems).

Comment: This worked, although I had difficulty getting it to apply. Had to disconnect/reconnect several times, and delete duplicate connections that kept being created.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution, where you do not use `network-manager` anymore to manage your wireless interface, but you directly use `wpa_supplicant`. This means in Ubuntu you won't have the convenience anymore to use your GUI to select between networks.

Here is what you need to do:

**1**
Enter this to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file (replace `wlan0` with the name of your wireless interface):

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This will cause `network-manager` not to manage the interface `wlan0` anymore.
If you want to revert this behaviour, please simply comment out what you added in this file.

**2**
Create/edit the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with the following content:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
    ssid="Your_AP"
    psk="Your_Passphrase"
    freq_list=2412 2437 2462
}
```

The values after `freq_list` have to be adapted by you. They secify the center frequency of the allowed channels to which you want to connect. In the case of the above example, I have added the channels 1, 6 and 11 of the 2.4 GHz band. The center frequencies for the 5 GHz band can be found e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5GHz).

Comment: I created the two differant SSID's for two band 1 for 2.4GHz and 1 for 5GHz.